# passing json array with spaces to bash script for az cli tagging

Tags: json, bash, az

I have a bash script that looks like the following and correctly passes tags to the az cli that includes spaces.

```
RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME=$1
LOCATION=$2
TAGS_INPUT_ARGUMENT=$3 # This TAGS_INPUT_ARGUMENT needs to finally look like the TAGS below.

echo 'TAGS_INPUT_ARGUMENT:' $TAGS_INPUT_ARGUMENT

# HARD CODED TAGS that Work
TAGS=("owner=Firstname Lastname" "application=cool-name")
echo 'TAGS:' "${TAGS[@]}"

az group create \
--name $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME \
--location $LOCATION \
--tags "${TAGS[@]}"
```

I am having problems passing the TAGS into the script.
i.e.

```
export TAGS='["owner=Firstname Lastname","application=cool-name"]'
bash ./entrypoint.sh rg-lionking eastus2  "${TAGS}"
```

**Output:**

```
TAGS_INPUT_ARGUMENT: ["owner=Firstname Lastname","application=cool-name"]
TAGS: owner=Firstname Lastname application=cool-name
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/**REDACTED**/resourceGroups/rg-lionking",
  "location": "eastus2",
  "managedBy": null,
  "name": "rg-lionking",
  "properties": {
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
  },
  "tags": {
    "application": "cool-name",
    "owner": "Firstname Lastname"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups"
}
```

Given that I can get TAGS in a good state, what do I need to do to pass in the same thing in json format and get it working as the final argument to the az group create cli?

My jp knowledge is practically zero, so I am guessing that the answer lies in there somewhere.

Comment: your hardcode TAGS values in the script and the one which you are exporting has a difference [ ] was used instead of () 

Next , can you post the error what your getting , Add a echo statement to print the $3 value

Comment: I updated with echo ouput.  I have been trying to convert that $3 input into something that I know az cli likes using a bunch of jp stuff.  My hope is that this problem is how do  I convert $3 which is a [] into a proper ().

Comment: You can't export an array; the environment can only hold regular strings. That said, I don't see *why* you're trying to use `export` here.

Comment: BTW, all-caps names in shell are used for variables that either modify or reflect how the shell (or other POSIX-specified tools) behave; see the standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, reserving names with lowercase characters for application use. As a script author, you're writing an application, so you should take advantage of having that namespace reserved for your use. :)

Comment: (...similarly, using `.sh` extensions for *bash* scripts is problematic; `.sh` implies that something can be run with / sourced by `/bin/sh`, which isn't the case, and executables on UNIX don't conventionally have extensions anyhow -- you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`, and `pip`, not `pip.py`; when writing a shell *library*, intended to be sourced, _then_ it's appropriate to give it an extension -- `.sh` if it's POSIX-compliant, `.bash` if it uses bashisms, `.ksh` if it uses the ksh variant on the language, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to expanding an array is on the command line is passing multiple separate arguments

```
./entrypoint rg-lionking eastus2 "owner=Firstname Lastname" "application=cool-name"
```

...and then, in `entrypoint`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
resource_group_name=$1; shift
location=$1; shift
tags=( "$@" )

az group create \
  --name "$resource_group_name" \
  --location "$location" \
  --tags "${tags[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks Charles.  To give more context.  My sh is a docker entry point via a github action.  I think they only allow strings as arguments, so tags=() isn't something that can control as the input argument.  Thats why I was trying to pass a json string in.  BTW: I was using export just as a convenience.

Comment: `"${tags[@]}"` just expands to a list of strings, each as its own distinct argument. So `tags=( "owner=Firstname Lastname" "application=cool-name" )` and then using `./entrypoint rg-lionking eastus2 "${tags[@]}"` is **exactly** the same as `./entrypoint rg-lionking eastus2 "owner=Firstname Lastname" "application=cool-name"`.

Comment: (re: "using export as a convenience", how is `export foo=bar` more convenient than just `foo=bar`, the version that sets a regular shell variable instead of an environment variable?)

Comment: why is tags='"owner=Firstname Lastname" "application=cool-name"', followed by passing it a "${tags}" treated differently then what is 2 arguments here "owner=Firstname Lastname" "application=cool-name"?  The github action yaml only lets me add that whole thing as a single entry.  i.e.  tags: '"owner=Firstname Lastname" "application=cool-name"'

Comment: Your stuff works btw, but now whatever bash github actions is using is choking on the "tags=( "$@" )" -- /entrypoint.sh: line 17: syntax error: unexpected "(".  I don't get this error using windows WSL ubuntu

Comment: @HerbStahl, that implies you're running it with `sh`, not bash. It's bash-only code; `sh` is not expected to work with it anywhere.

Comment: @HerbStahl, ...that said, you can just use `--tags "$@"`, and that'll work even with `/bin/sh`.